# Difference between clinical significance and statistical significance

Tags: database, errors, validation, p-values

I am working on a clinical data analysis project and am from IT domain.

While I am analyzing the data, I came to know that though some of the variables are not statistically significant, they are clinically significant.

I also read that difference in median values between case and control group for variables is used as a measure to indicate clinical significance

Can someone help me understand this with a simple example as to why difference in median between groups is considered for clinical significance?

Comment: nice and a great question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another viewpoint could be : statistically significant implies use of sampling theory to establish presence of significant difference  between  case and control groups. The "clinical " significance seems to test for correctness or validity of measures of variables. Apparenty, the measurement theory is meant for checking validity of data - the difference  could arise on account of incorrect measurements. The non-parameteric tests -  it seems - take care of measurement errors and hence, produce perhaps more reliable results.

Comment: Thanks upvoted for the response

Answer (score 3):

This is non-parametric statistics, the mean requires conformation to the normal distribution (but there are exceptions), or perhaps better put it requires a fixed relationship between mean and standard deviation. Non-parametric stats always use the median and are distribution free. Wilcoxon test/ Mann-Whitney U test  are used to replace t-test. The Kruskal-Wallis test replaces the 1-way ANOVA
Finally the Friedman test replaces 2-way ANOVA but has its critiques.  The t- and ANOVA tests require normality, F-max is one approach to determine normality.

Comment: Thanks. upvoted for the response

Comment: :-) thanks @subhash, likewise.