# In medical and public health care, should we make use of "clinical" signficance testing (non-parametric tests) or parametric tests of significance?"

Tags: statistics, biostatistics, inference, non-parametric

In certain cases, traditional significance test may not be able to identify that effect of a treatment or a drug is significant. However,clinical significance test may suggest a significant effect. Does it mean that this test is a better way of interpreting  effect-size or correlation coefficient when we are facing imperfect measurements or data. Imperfect measurements could produce a wrong conclusion based on traditional statistical test?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you give us an example where the significance test indicates a lack of significance (with good experimental design) but other evidence says otherwise?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is just too broad a question. If you [edit] and give a specific example we might be able to help if it is about bioinformatics, but as it stands, we cannot help you assess the results of a statistical test you haven't shown.

Comment: @RamRS please have a look. https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/11043/difference-between-clinical-significance-and-statistical-significance

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, @SubhashC.Davar

Comment: @Ram RS Meta Analysis: please read my paper - An Improved Version of Hunter, Schmidt and Jackson Framework.